# Updating website pages

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been looking for this simple question for a while. If I have 5 pages with say 5 images, how do I put new content on the first page and have the images on that page continue on to the next page and so on. That way I can keep 5 images on the page. I really don't want to manually move every image to the next page. (I'm trying to ask about pagination but at the time I was clueless.)

Edit:

This was my first question ever on stack overflow and reading it back a couple years later is quite embarrassing. On a side note its kind of fun to see how far I've come as I have now built a website with hundreds of pages using pagination.

Answer (score 2):

If you talking about static pages(like those stored on your hard drive) that just use HTML,CSS and JavaScript then unfortunately this can't be done.If you are using dynamic page generation using server side technologies like  PHP,ASP.NET or JAVA etc then its a child's play.

Since you didn't specify any server side language i highly doubt that's the case.